# Why does @jit is rounding my function result?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I'm defining a function as:

```
@jit
def u(x):
    if gamma == 1:
        return(math.log(x))
    else:
        return (x**(1-gamma)-1)/(1-gamma)
```

But then the function is rounding all my results. For example, when I don't use @jit, u(10) returns me 0.249975, but when I use it, the function returns me 0.25

I need the result to be precise, can anyone help me?

Comment: Forgot to mention that my parameter gamma = 5

Comment: From http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.17.0/user/jit.html it seems you should specify the type of x on the @jit line, likely to float64

Comment: yw. You can post the new line as your own answer to the question, and accept it, it may help someone else later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has worked:

```
@jit("float64(float64)")
def u(x):
    if gamma == 1:
        return(math.log(x))
    else:
        return (x**(1-gamma)-1)/(1-gamma)
```